# Logout with UnityEngine.Social in unity

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I use UnityEngine.Social to login my user on googleplaygames or ios:

```
    Social.localUser.Authenticate(ProcessAuthentication);
```

This work fine, but now I would like to make my user hable to disconnect. But the Social or ILocalUser the class do not contain any method to disconnect. I don't find how do it cleanly and keep the abstraction of google or ios system if possible.

Thank you - sorry for english error -

Comment: Mmmhh... no, [no work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0xlZ.png) This chek run also after many seconds (under a Update function), it is not a matter of waiting for the log out... You need to check Social.Active.localUser.authenticated variable.

Comment: I don't have the code I have use anymore to help you :/
Maybe Google+ and GooglePlayGames don't work same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sign out from googleplaygames simply using this:

```
using GooglePlayGames;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SignOut ();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Zeldarck You can sign out from google play games as @Jindra Žák said but for iOS Game center it is not to log out as iOS not provide a way to do it.Refer for iOS game center [here](https:////forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-sign-out-game-center-using-social-api.371019/)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! However, as this is not really an answer, it would have been more appropriate to add a comment to @JindraŽák's answer.